# Assign value to variable unique to div, and pass varaible to Component function In React

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs

Below is a `React.Component` running on Meteor.js, hence the `Session` functions which are global.

For each `div` inside `div#sidebar-wrapper`, the same value `foo` or `bar` is passed into the methods `this.isActive` and `this.changeTab`.

```
<div 
    className={this.isActive('foo') + " tab-btn"}
    onClick={this.changeTab.bind(null, 'foo')}>
    <span className="title">Foo</span>
</div>
```

**Question:** Is it possible to assign this value `foo` or `bar` to the `div` as a variable, and pass this variable into the 2 functions? The idea is to make the code cleaner.

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Sidebar extends React.Component {

    isActive(tabName) {
        return status = Session.get('currentTab') == tabName ? "active" : "";
    }

    changeTab(tabName) {
        Session.set('currentTab', tabName);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
                <div 
                    className={this.isActive('foo') + " tab-btn"}
                    onClick={this.changeTab.bind(null, 'foo')}>
                    <span className="title">Foo</span>
                </div>

                <div 
                    className={this.isActive('bar') + " tab-btn"}
                    onClick={this.changeTab.bind(null, 'bar')}>
                    <span className="title">Bar</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the `div` into its own reusable component, something like:

```
export default class InnerDiv extends React.Component {

    isActive(tabName) {
        return status = Session.get('currentTab') == tabName ? "active" : "";
    }

    changeTab(tabName) {
        Session.set('currentTab', tabName);
    }

    render() {
        var title = this.props.title;
        var titleLowerCase = title.toLowerCase();

        return (
            <div>
                className={this.isActive(titleLowerCase) + " tab-btn"}
                onClick={this.changeTab.bind(null, titleLowerCase)}>
                <span className="title">title</span>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

And then change then `render` method of `Sidebar` to a way cleaner one:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
            <InnerDiv title="Foo" /> 
            <InnerDiv title="Bar" /> 
        </div>
    )
}
```

I took the liberty to assume the the `Session` variable is a global one, and there is not issue moving the `isActive` and `changeTab` functions into the new component. If this is an issue, please tell me and I will propose another solution.